# How to attach jquery to click() event when HTML is generated dynamically?

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using the JQUeryUI to present a Dialog Box to the end user and populating it with dynamically generated HTML like this.

```
$('#listusers').click(function() {
    $("#dialog").html("");
    $("#dialog").attr("title", "Existing Users");
    $("#dialog").load("service/get.aspx?data=users", $(function(data) { $("#dialog").dialog({ modal: true }); }));
});
```

The HTML that is returned from "service/get.aspx?data=users" looks like this.

```
<div class="ui-widget" id="users-contain">
    <h1>Existing Users:</h1>
<table class="ui-widget ui-widget-content" id="users">
    <thead>
        <tr class="ui-widget-header">
            <th>Act</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="#" class="deleteuser" id="0delete">
                    <img src="images/49.gif" alt="help">
                </a>
            </td>
            <td id="0username">JoePlumber</td>
            <td>joe@mcain2008.org</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="#" class="deleteuser" id="1delete">
                    <img src="images/49.gif" alt="help">
                </a>
            </td>
            <td id="1username">SarahPalin</td>
            <td>sarah@cliffnotes.com</td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

My question is if I want to attach some jquery to the click event of all elements with a class of deleteuser like this

```
$(".deleteuser").click(function() {
        alert('help');
    });
```

Where do I put this code?

I tried like this but no luck

```
$('#delete-user').click(function() {
    $("#dialog").html("");
    $("#dialog").attr("title", "Existing Users");
    $("#dialog").load("service/get.aspx?data=users", $(function(data) { $("#dialog").dialog({ modal: true }); }));
    $(".deleteuser").click(function() {
        alert('help');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your main document.ready function, add this:

```
$(".deleteuser").live('click',function() {
        alert('help');
    });
```

live() binds the event to all occurence of the selector, including those that are not present at the time of the function call, meaning, for all elements called via ajax.
[See the doc](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Answer (score 2):

use live binding - http://api.jquery.com/live/

`$(".delete-user").live("click", function(evt){

       [ do stuff ]
});`